# Translation of the English word "Set" as a verb

Tags: traduction

I have a program where a user can set the value of an (HTML) attribute, like `height`, `width`, `title` etc.

How can I translate "Set" (as in "Set height") into French?

Comment: dimensionner un élément HTML, aussi, par exemple. spécifier la hauteur [du bloc]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways to say it, the most common being probably:

> ***Définir** la hauteur* (prevent the value to be undefined)

> ***Fixer** la hauteur*  (prevent the value to vary)

> ***Spécifier** la hauteur* suggested by Lambie in a comment would also work and is more formal.

Comment: I chose to use Fixer.

Comment: « Fixer » implique une valeur constante plus fortement que « définir ». En programmation, « fixer » est aussi parfois utilisé avec une teinte d'anglicisme provenant de « *to fix* », corriger (un bug, un problème). Le choix « définir » ici me semble beaucoup plus adapté.

Comment: @Blackhole C'est vrai que *fixer* se dit de plus en plus pour *corriger*, mais surtout à l'oral il me semble, pas encore trop dans une interface utilisateur.